# How to instantiate Marker in L.geoJSON pointToLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When I include the following code no markers appear and the errors in the  console are:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function at pointToLayer.

If you know of any solutions please share.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [53.423933, -7.94069], 
            zoom: 7,
            layers: [grayscale]
        });

var url = "howdy.json";

var geojsonMarkerOptions = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'howdy.png',
            iconSize:     [16, 28], 
            iconAnchor:   [8, 18], 
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -13] 
        });

function forEachFeature(feature, layer) {

        var popupContent = 
        feature.properties.Cabin+
        feature.properties.Crew + 
        feature.properties.Mobile;

        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
            popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
        }
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        };

      var howdy = L.geoJSON(null, {
        onEachFeature: forEachFeature, 
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.Marker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        }
  });

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        Shelter.addData(data);
});

Shelter.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the error is caused by your line:

```js
return L.Marker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
```

...where you try instantiating a Leaflet Marker calling the `L.Marker` *class constructor* without the `new` JavaScript keyword that triggers instantiation.

Note the difference with Leaflet's provided *factory* `L.marker` (lowercase first letter `m`), which is simply an alias for `new L.Marker`.

Comment: Hi @ghybs your sugesstion worked nicely. However the markers are now being displayed as default and not as L.icon

Comment: Hum looks like you make a 2nd mistake. Refer to Leaflet doc for Marker options. Your `L.icon` should be passed to `icon` option, not directly to `L.marker` 2nd argument. Please feel free to open a new question for this different issue should you need further help.

Comment: Got it. Just needed to alter the line return new L.Marker(latlng, {icon: geojsonMarkerOptions});